# Convert display equations alone to SVG format using TeX4ht

Tags: tex4ht, svg

My codes are follows:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

This is for test $a+b=c$
\begin{align}
\sum+\prod=\int
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

I need to convert the `inline math` into standard `HTML+Unicode` format (which comes correctly), but all the `display math` should convert into `SVG` format, generally, I'm using the below command to convert from `TeX to HTML`:

```
htlatex filename "xhtml" " -cunihft" " -cvalidate -p"
```

Please advise

Comment: Since MathML support has recently (finally) been added to Chromium, it is available in all major web browsers. So is using SVG for math on the web really relevant anymore?

Comment: @Gaussler This is an intention request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can request conversion to SVG pictures using the `svg` option. You need also some additional options to request `align` and other environments to pictures, see `pic-align` and following options in the [documentation](https://www.kodymirus.cz/tex4ht-doc/texfourhtOptions.html#-texht-options1).

There is also issue with your command. One issue is that `htlatex` is deprecated, you should use `make4ht` instead. The other issue is the `-p` option that you use in your last argument. It blocks conversion of pictures, so no picture will be created even if you use correct options.

So the correct command is something like:

```
$ make4ht -m draft -a debug  filename.tex "xhtml,svg,pic-align"
```

The `-m draft` option is used for faster conversion, `-a debug` will print full LaTeX output and other info, if you are interested in that.

This is the result:

[image]

Comment: This works well, just for a clarification, is this any possibility to do this conversion by using `htlatex`?

Comment: @MadyYuvi yes, something like `htlatex filename.tex "xhtml,svg,pic-align"` should work.

Comment: It's working fine, how can include the option  `-m draft` in `htlatex`? Please advise

Comment: @MadyYuvi `htlatex` doesn't support the draft mode and other features.

Comment: Much thanks for the confirmation, it's really helpful a lot

Comment: @MadyYuvi it is really better to use `make4ht`, because it has much more features and fixes some issues: https://www.kodymirus.cz/make4ht/make4ht-doc.html#difference-of-makeht-from-htlatex

Comment: Yes sure, will move to `make4ht` soon, just I'm confirming, that's all, you are one of my mentor, how can I skip your words? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Just for a clarification, is this possible to convert the entire equations (both inline and display) into `SVG` format by using `htlatex`? Please advise.

Comment: @MadyYuvi yes, see the `pic-m` option. You will probably need also other options for various AMS math environments. Note that with `make4ht`, you can use the `dvisvgm_hashes` extension, which can considerably speed up the compilation time. See https://www.kodymirus.cz/tex4ht-doc/Howto.html#picture-math for example.

Comment: I've tried `make4ht -f html5+dvisvgm_hashes filename.tex "pic-m,pic-equation,svg`, but it produced the error as `...cripts/make4ht/extensions/make4ht-ext-dvisvgm_hashes.lua:48: bad argument #1 to 'find' (string expected, got nil)` Please advise.

Comment: @MadyYuvi I will need a full example and a full log produced by the `-a debug`, to be able to find what is the cause of this bug.

Comment: Sorry, fixed the error, some LaTeX tag had error, corrected it and converted successfully.

Comment: @MadyYuvi could you post it anyway, with the error? `make4ht` shouldn't fail the compilation with the fatal error, it is quite serious bug.

Comment: Sorry, hope my statement was wrong, it was a coding error, nothing issues in `Make4ht`, mistake in my TeX file and later I've corrected it, hope this is clear now.

Comment: @MadyYuvi I understand that, but `make4ht` still shouldn't crash because of an error in the TeX code, I should fix this issue.

Comment: Ok will send it